# Link can be submitted in answer, but editing says it's not allowed

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

So [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/23670/5733) has a link to Hollywood Reporter.

His links aren't formatted properly, so when it came up in the review thread I decided to clean it up a bit and tell him how to properly link (he's a new user, no biggie), but then the editor is telling me that links to Hollywood Reporter aren't allowed.

So how is it that a user can add them when answering a question, but when editing it gets all mean and says nope? Possible bug?

Further, should these questions be edited to remove the link to a source that's not allowed, and if so, how should they be edited?

Comment: The even bigger question would be why on earth a link to Hollywood Reporter is not allowed.

Comment: Edited it and it worked fine, so I'm not sure what happened there.

Comment: @SonnyBurnett I was wondering that myself, but yeah, the editor was telling me that links to Hollywood Reporter are not allowed.

Comment: @MattD - can you edit it now?

Comment: Hopped into the editor and copied the Hollywood Reporter link. Simply added, "This." to the post and applied link formatting to it. Then typed a few more gibberish lines. Waited about 30 seconds, and no error message about not being able to link to Hollywood Reporter came up.